# Bug in Stack Overflow new reputation menu

Tags: support, reputation-history, achievements-dialog

I got two times 10 reputation points. So it should be showing 20. But it shows 1010 as shown in:

[image: This image]

Comment: are you sure it didn't just total all your 100 rep association bonuses from the other sites? your profile says you're on 10 sites including SO, and 10*100 = 1000 and you got your association bonus ~23 minutes ago. remember that the rep notification there is network wide, not just SO

Comment: ohk..thats grate ..its my mistake ..i recently noticed that...
thanks for explanation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you are seeing your association bonus. If we look at your reputation points,

[image: Reputation]

we see that ~44 minutes ago when I loaded that page you got your [association bonus](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/08/cross-site-account-associations/) of 100 reputation points:

> All very good, but here’s the exciting part: there is a +100 reputation bonus for every association you make, if either the source or target account in the association has at least 200 reputation.

If we look at your communities,

[image: Communities]<sub>1</sub>

we see you have 10. 10 x 100 = 1000.

The extra 10 you are seeing is the 10 reputation points you got which pushed your reputation on Stack Overflow past 200. As we can see in the first image, we see you got +10 ~44 minutes ago as well.

Just remember that the **Recent achievements:** button along with your index on the top nav bar is network wide. If you got reputation points, badges or notifications on another site while you're on Stack Overflow you're going to see them in here too.

---

<sub>1: The screenshots were taken at different times, and reputation points might be different.</sub>